# Can't install wptools with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-analysis, wikipedia-api, audacity

> error: (60, 'SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired')

when I try to install wptools tools by **pip install wptools** i get the above error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.